# Julia: fastest way to count number of unique elements in a sorted array possibly containing missing

Tags: julia

The key is that the array is sorted and may contain missing elements. I suspect `length(unique(arr))` may not be the fastest.

I am wondering if there is a pre-built function that can deal such a case?

Answer (score 3):

Julia's [implementation of `unique(itr)`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a6de8b6186285244954df0e5fdfab17958e4a62a/base/set.jl#L101) is quite efficient for arbitrary collections--the time scales approximately linearly with the size of the input collection. However, because it constructs two lookup dictionaries to help identify which elements it has seen before, the amount of memory it allocates scales with the number of unique elements in the collection. If you know the input collection is already sorted, you can take advantage of this to reduce the allocations and speed up the count significantly:

```
function nunique(a)
    last = first(a)
    n = 1
    for x in a
        if isless(last, x)
            n += 1
            last = x
        end
    end
    n
end

r = Array{Union{Missing,Int64}}(rand(1:10000, 100000))  # 100_000 elements, 10_000 unique
r[rand(1:length(r), 100)] .= missing                    # 100 missing elements
sort!(r)

@time length(unique(r))
# 0.002156 seconds (37 allocations: 503.781 KiB)
# 10001

@time nunique(r)
# 0.000464 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
# 10001
```

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in function that optimizes for the special case of sorted input arrays.

This function will still scale in time like the size of the input collection, but it is only making one (!) allocation, so it sheds all of the overhead involved with creating lookup dictionaries.

Of course, this function will only work if the array is already sorted according to the `isless` function. You can add a check while iterating to abort and switch to the `length(unique(itr))` version if necessary:

```
function nunique2(a)
    last = first(a)
    n = 1
    for x in a
        if isless(last, x)
            n += 1
            last = x
        elseif !isequal(last, x)
            return length(unique(a))
        end
    end
    n
end

@time nunique2(r)
# 0.000256 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
# 10001

using Random
shuffle!(r)
@time nunique2(r)
# 0.002801 seconds (37 allocations: 503.781 KiB)
# 10001
```

As with all microbenchmarks, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I have a parallel solution but sadly it is only 30% faster on 6 threads

```
function nunique(v)
    @assert length(v) > 0
    cnt = 1
    lasta::eltype(v) = first(v)
    @inbounds for newa1 in v
        if !isequal(newa1, lasta)
            cnt += 1
            lasta = newa1
        end
    end
    cnt
end

""" Parallelized version """
function pnunique(v)
    nt = Threads.nthreads()
    lo::Vector{Int} = collect(0:div(length(v), nt):length(v)-1)
    hi::Vector{Int} = lo[2:end]
    hi[end] = length(v)
    lo = lo .+ 1

    nu = Vector{Int}(undef, nt)

    Threads.@threads for i in 1:nt
        @inbounds nu[i] = nunique(@view v[lo[i]:hi[i]])
    end

    res = sum(nu)
    for j in 1:nt-1
        @inbounds res -= v[hi[j]] == v[lo[j+1]]
    end

    res
end
```